# Remote Session Detection Artifact for Zoom.exe

Tags: windows, remote-access, zoom-meeting

I have an incident which requires me to check whether there was remote session provided by user using Zoom.exe on a Windows10 machine.

I tried to search for any related event logs and used procmon.exe to look for any unique .dll loaded when there is a remote session, but I cannot find any special dll, and I cannot use netstat to confirm this because the zoom session was 1 day ago; also there are no Zoom logs I can use to look for remote sessions.

Is there any artifact I can extract from the user side which I can use to confirm that there was a remote session?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom has logs: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201512326-Troubleshooting-Log-for-PC

I don't know for certain whether or not these logs contain the information you need, or how it will be noted, but I would guess they do.

> Navigate to the log files, which are located at the following
> location:
> Win7+: C:\Users\your account\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\logs
> XP: C:\Documents and Settings\your account\Application Data\Zoom\logs

Comment: I checked it before but unfortunately there is no logs I believe this log folder is for technical troubleshooting Zoom.exe.